# Some IBOutlets are nil in multiple Nib application

Tags: iphone

I have a multiple Nib application, and in my `awakeFromNib:` method, some `IBOutlet`s are nil.

I think I have narrowed down the problem, but I'm not sure why. I have a `MainWindow.xib` file, that was created by Xcode. In there, I have the application delegate, and several view controllers (one per each other Nib I have). Let's call one of them the `MatrixViewController`.

I also have a `MatrixView.xib` file, where I have the controller and the view. What I want to do is from `MatrixViewController`'s `awakeFromNib` initialize something from its view. However, all the outlets in it are nil.

I think this is because the `awakeFromNib:` I'm responding to was sent when loading `MainWindow.xib` and not `MatrixView.xib`, am I correct?

What is the alternative to solve this? One good thing about it, is that all the initialization is done when the application loads, which I'd like to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-viewDidLoad` instead of `-awakeFromNib`

It's one of those iPhone vs MacOSX differences.

Answer (score 2):

The IBOutlets should only be referenced from viewDidLoad if you want to change them before the view is displayed.

The nib may not have been loaded when awakeFromNib is called.